# Display data using kendoChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I wonder why I cant display my result query using the kendoChart. when i tried this

```
series: [{
   type: "pie",
   data: [{
      category: "Available",
      value: 24
   }]
}],
```

It works!

but when i tried to put the result of my query (please see the picture below)

```
series: [{
   type: "pie",
   data: [{
      category: status,
      value: counts
   }]
}],
```

no record display

my current code:

```
<script>
  const createChart = async () =>{
     const { status, counts } = await getConditions();
     console.log(status, counts)
     $("#chart1").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "All Books"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "top"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                labels: {
                    template: "#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#",
                    position: "outsideEnd",
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent"
                }
            },
          series: [{
                type: "pie",
                data: [{
                    category: status,
                    value: counts
                }]
            }],
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage) #"
            }
        }); 
}
$(document).ready(()=>{
    createChart();
});
</script>
```

the results data from the console.log(status, counts)

[image]

Comment: So `status` is an array, not a string; `counts` is an array, not a number. Looks like something to _iterate_ over. Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: hello @SebastianSimon, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: See [forEach loop through two arrays at the same time in javascript](/q/57903061/4642212). `data` is an array of objects. Perhaps map both arrays, i.e. `status` (by value) and `counts` (by index) (or vice-versa), into objects like `{ category:`…`, value:`…`}`. I’m not a Kendo UI dev, but I’d _guess_ that …`series: [ { type: "pie", data: status.map((category, index) => ({ category, value: counts[index] })) } ]`… is worth exploring. Read the Kendo UI documentation to find out if this structure makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `status` and `counts` are arrays, you'll need to convert it to an array of objects (with `category` and `value` fields) Kendo can understand. See example below and try it in the Telerik DOJO.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/styles/kendo.default-main.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.301/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart1">
    </div>
    <script>
  const createChart = async () =>{
     //const { status, counts } = await getConditions();
     //console.log(status, counts)
     // better ensure that status and counts are of the same length!
     let status = ["Not Available",
                   "Not Available",
                   "Not Available",
                   "Not Available",
                   "Available",
                   "Available",
                   "Available"];
     let counts = [7,
                   7,
                   7,
                   7,
                   7,
                   7,
                   7];
     let data = [];
     for (let a = 0; a < status.length; a++) {
       data.push({
         category: status[a],
         value: counts[a]
       });
     }
     $("#chart1").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "All Books"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "top"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                labels: {
                    template: "#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#",
                    position: "outsideEnd",
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent"
                }
            },
          series: [{
                type: "pie",
                data: data,
            }],
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage) #"
            }
        }); 
}
$(document).ready(()=>{
    createChart();
});
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```